# How to restore a ML content db from single node to a 3-node-cluster

Tags: marklogic

I have a single-node ML dev environment. I already took a db backup.
My objective is to restore that db backup to a 3-node ML Cluster for qa.

In order to make the db set up the same, I have already retired the content -2 and content-3 db. Hence in 3-node ML cluster there is only one content forest same as the single-node dev environment.

However, I could see some strange messages like below.

[image]

Moreoever I do not expect to see **is-data-dir** message next to the db.

Here is the error message after clicking restore.

[image: Restore Error Messsage]

FYI:

1. I did try to restore the very same db backup on another single node ML successfully.
2. In the past I did successfully do the same things before but it is the reverse way. I restore a DB back from a 3 node cluster to a single node. The trick I did last time is to create three content forests on that single node.
3. Both dev and qa are based on the same ML version.

Comment: It is not helpful if you just say that you got a permission error. Post the error, so that we can see what it says. But in general, if you don't have proper permissions to read the backup or perform the restore, then it won't work. Knowing what the permission error was will help indicate what the issue is.

Comment: +1 to @MadsHansen. Are you getting permission error because the `user` is not having privileges to read from old cluster and/or write to the new cluster (OR) stored your backup in S3 and you no longer have access to that backup bucket?

Comment: You could also use MLCP to copy the data from one cluster to another (no need to retire/disable additional nodes/forests).

Comment: Great thanks for the quick reply. I have updated the original ticket to include some screenshots. For this case, I could not use MLCP to copy data between different environments as the total data size is over 150G. There are some big binary files inside. It will end up with time-out error to copy those binary files. The fastest way might be use backup and restore.

Comment: I would like to first to confirm whether it is possible to backup and restore from different cluster configurations. For this case, it is from a single node cluster to a 3-node cluster.  If that is possible, we could go into detail on what is wrong in my operational steps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that you are pointing to a directory that is not a backup directory. MarkLogic backup directories will start with a dateTime of when the backup was taken and will look something like: `20230529-1837423059969`.

Maybe you are pointing to the parent directory of where a backup was taken?

**is-data-dir** is indicating that the directory is a MarkLogic data directory.

It's generally a good idea to put your backups in an area that is separate from the forest data. When you see that, it makes me question if this is a backup location, or if it is - whether you had copied the backup folders to `/var/opt/MarkLogic/ml-backups`. You should put your backups in a different location.

If you attempt to create a backup inside of the MarkLogic data directory, you will get an error: [XDMP-BACKDATADIR](https://docs.marklogic.com/11.0/messages/XDMP-en/XDMP-BACKDATADIR). The error page explains that it's a bad idea to put your backups there:

> The configured backup directory is the same as, or is a sub-directory of, MarkLogic's data directory.

> Your backup directory may not be inside the MarkLogic Server installation or data area. For example, on Unix, you should not save your backups under `/var/opt/MarkLogic` or `/opt/MarkLogic`.

Comment: It works now. I could restore db backup from single node to a 3-node cluster.